# jQuery - Adding class with an increment of 3

Tags: jquery

I have a basic line of jQuery that adds a class plus a number that increases for a database output e.g. the output below:

```
<div class="panelCon">
<div class="panel01">Content</div>
<div class="panel02">Content</div>
<div class="panel03">Content</div>
<div class="panel04">Content</div>
<div class="panel05">Content</div>
<div class="panel06">Content</div>
</div>
```

What i'm struggling with is the math/code to output the divs but in a cycle of 1 to 3 e.g.

```
<div class="panelCon">    
<div class="panel01">Content</div>
<div class="panel02">Content</div>
<div class="panel03">Content</div>
<div class="panel01">Content</div>
<div class="panel02">Content</div>
<div class="panel03">Content</div>
</div>
```

Probably basic stuff but I can't easily find a reference to help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uvuvan/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
$(".panelCon > div").each(function( i ){
    $(this).addClass('panel0'+ ((i%3)+1) );
});
```

Or like:

```
$('.panelCon > div').addClass(function( i ) {
    return "panel0" + ((i%3)+1) ;
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators
http://api.jquery.com/each/ (where `i` represents the *index* of the element in the array (collection).)
http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the callback to `addClass` and the modulo operator:

```
$('.panelCon > div').addClass(function(index) {
    return 'panel0' + ((index % 3) + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly easy with the callback signature to `addClass`:

```
$('div.panelCon div').addClass(function(idx, oldClass) {
    return 'panel' + ((idx % 3) + 1);
});
```

If you are adding the classes for the purposes of styling, however, you might be better off with the `nth-child` CSS selector:

```
div.panelCon div:nth-child(3n+1) {
    /* styles for the first column */
}
div.panelCon div:nth-child(3n+2) {
    /* styles for the second column */
}
div.panelCon div:nth-child(3n) {
    /* styles for the third column */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var i = 1;
            $(".panelCon").children("div").each(function(){
                $(this).addClass("panel0" + i);
                if(i == 3){
                    i = 0;
                }
                i++;
            });
```

Comment: Thanks! This works as well as well as couple of others with more compact code.